# Reference a dynamic role name in a Cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, iaas

In one Cloudformation template I create the following role:

```
  CRMPiccoRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'crm-${Environment}-register'
```

In another Cloudformation template for an EC2 instance I am attempting to attach that role to my EC2 instance, however I am unsure how to reference a *dynamic* role name.

```
Resources:
  InstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - !Ref 'crm-${Environment}-register'
```

Can this be done?

When I attempt to validate the template I get an error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate
> operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies
> [crm-${Environment}-register] in the Resources block of the template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ref` does not work across stacks. Assuming you are using **same account and region**, instead you have to use [Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) and [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) functions.

So in your **first stack** you would have:

```
  CRMPiccoRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub 'crm-${Environment}-register'

Outputs:

   MyCRMPiccoRole:
     Value: !Ref CRMPiccoRole
     Export:
        Name: !Sub 'crm-${Environment}-register'
```

Then in the **second stack**:

```
Resources:
  InstanceProfile:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile'
    Properties:
      Path: /
      Roles:
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub 'crm-${Environment}-register'
```